# Image files do not load in GitHub repository

Tags: image, github, readme

My [GitHub repo](https://github.com/drkndl/Generative-Art) does not load images (all of them .png files). This includes the images in my README that I have added using relative paths from the repo. Most images are a few kB in size.

I have checked to see if there are any issues with my relative image paths. Some answers to other questions suggested it could be an issue with the case sensitivity. I have checked all of this and it doesn't change.

What's strange is that I have had this repo for months, and did not have this issue until the last month or so. Images used to load correctly and I haven't changed any paths to the images in the README.

So why are the images not loading in my GitHub repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the images on that link.

Comment: Must be an issue from my side then. Bizarre. Thanks Mike.

Comment: The whole concept of generative art reminds me of Sol LeWitt btw. @justauser

Comment: Yes! He's one of the pioneers! :)